# How to find a bus stop in array by a route?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, find

i've got a problem.

We've got a route that serves multiple bus stops.

We've got one bus stop from the whole route.

Now how to find the stop that goes next on this route?

The "_stopNum": "1" means the stop is the first in route

Stop example:

```
{
  "route": [
    {
      "_transport": "regionalbus",
      "_num": "146",
      "_direction": "b-a",
      "_directionName": "Nõva - Harju-Risti - Padise - Ämari - Keila  - Harku - Tallinn",
      "_stopNum": "1"
    }
  ],
  "_id": "5701054-1",
  "_id0": "134773",
  "_name": "Laimi",
  "_lat": "59.22155",
  "_lon": "23.67992"
}
```

[I've made a scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wr7I.png) that can help to understand the problem.

and also a screenshot of a part of array [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUQbj.png)

I tried to find through the .find function but did not figure out how to search for object in array of objects inside an object in an array of objects. i messed up sorry

Comment: how can you identify a stop to be  on same route? by `route[x]._num` ? what about `route[x]._direction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// first collect all stops from your array
let stops = routeData.map(a => a.route).flat()

// let's create a function that finds the next stop after a given stop
function getNextStop(currentStop) {
  // find the stop that has the same route number (_num) and the stop number increased by 1
  return stops.find(element => element._num === currentStop._num 
         && parseInt(currentStop._stopNum) + 1 == element._stopNum);
}
```

Just use the `getNextStop()` function and provide the `currentStop` to it. You can modify the search conditions in the `find()` by your needs, maybe you need to filter by the direction as well

Comment: I've made some editings to your code snipped and reached success! Thank you, Felix!